# Unable to Align the div in bootstrap html code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Unable to align the div in bootstrap html code as per design. I'm trying to align the drop down list, and 2 input boxes, on the left side of the page, in three rows. And the preview portion or div on the right hand side of the page.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/37gaq/1/

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="container-fuild">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="chartType">Chart type</label>

                    <div class="controls">
                        <select id="chartType" ng-change="selectType(chartType)" ng-model="chartType" ng-options="c.typeValue for c in chartTypes">
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span8">


            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="row-fluid">

                    <div class="control-group span6">
                        <label class="control-label" for="chartType">February server sale units</label>

                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" ng-model="chart.data.rows[1].c[3].v"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group span6">
                        <label class="control-label" for="chartType">Number of grid lines</label>

                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" ng-model="chart.options.vAxis.gridlines.count"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>

            <h2>Output</h2>

           <div id="chartDiv" style="{{chart.cssStyle}}">Preview Portion</div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: plz mention reason for down vote

Comment: The code is inconsistent with the Fiddle.

Comment: @Mooseman corrected ...plz now have a look

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to put the 3 controls one by row in the left and the div of the chart on the right. You should put all the controls inside the left sidebar and use the class "form-horizontal" of bootstrap

Here is a possible answer to your problem:

```
<div class="container-fuild">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="chartType">Chart type</label>

                    <div class="controls">
                        <select id="chartType" ng-change="selectType(chartType)" ng-model="chartType"
                                ng-options="c.typeValue for c in chartTypes">
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="chartType">February server sale units</label>

                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" ng-model="chart.data.rows[1].c[3].v"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="chartType">Number of grid lines</label>

                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" ng-model="chart.options.vAxis.gridlines.count"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span8"> 
            <h2>Output</h2>

            <div id="chartDiv" style="{{chart.cssStyle}}">Preview Portion</div> 
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```